Why proper cone can be used to define generalized inequality
I'm currenty studying convex optimization and in Stephen Boyd's Convex Optimization page 43, it mentioned that a cone $K\in R^n$ is called a proper cone if it satisfies the following:

$K$ is convex
$K$ is closed
$K$ is solid ,which means it has nonempty interior
$K$ is pointed, which means that it contains no line

The book then goes on to say that a proper cone
$
K$ can be used to define a generalized inequality. However, I am confused about why a proper cone can be used to define a generalized inequality. Later in the book, the concepts of minimum and minimal elements are introduced via dual inequalities. I don't intuitively understand what special properties of proper cones enable them to define generalized inequalities. Why can't non-proper cones be used in this way?

It looks like maybe you could answer your question if you tried doing exercise 2.30. (In other words, the conditions in the definition of proper cone are there to ensure that all those properties listed for generalized inequalities hold for the generalized inequality induced by the proper cone.) Did you already try doing that? My guess is that given a generalized inequality $\preceq$ meeting all those conditions, the set ${x \in \mathbb{R}^n| 0 \preceq x}$ is a proper cone, so the conditions for a proper cone are necessary and sufficient.
